# Magento 2.1 : Cannot retrieve session variable

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, session, di

Im trying to save form token in session variable and  get it back in the result page when the form is submitted.
I created the following Session Model to handle sessions in my custom module:

```
<?php

namespace My-Vendor\My-Module\Model;

class Session extends \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager
{

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface $sidResolver,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface $sessionConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandlerInterface $saveHandler,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\ValidatorInterface $validator,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\StorageInterface $storage,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $request,
        $sidResolver,
        $sessionConfig,
        $saveHandler,
        $validator,
        $storage,
        $cookieManager,
        $cookieMetadataFactory,
        $appState
    );
}


/**
 * Set Session data
 *
 * @param string|null $id
 * @return $this
 */
public function setSession($key,$data)
{
    $this->storage->setData($key, $data);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrieve Session data from current session
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getSession($key)
{
    if ($this->storage->getData($key)) {
        return $this->storage->getData($key);
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

The Index Block is injected with Session Model and then I set the session:

```
use My-Vendor\My-Module\Model\Session;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $sessionHandler;
public function __construct(...,Session $sessionHandler,...)
{
    ...
    $this->sessionHandler = $sessionHandler;
    ....
}

public function prepareFormToken()
{
    $token = Get the generated token...
    $this->sessionHandler->setSession('form_token',$token);
    return $token;
}

}
```

I can get the session variable from the Index Block using

```
$this->sessionHandler->setSession('form_token');
```

but I can't get it from the Result controller where the form is submitted to.

What's wrong with my code?